# need help to improve my Python script performance that uses nested loop and json file

Tags: python, json

I need help with improving my script's execution time.

It does what it suppose to do:

- Reads a file line by line
- Matches the line with the content of json file
- Writes both the matching lines with the corresponding information from json file into a new txt file

The problem is with execution time, the file has more than 500,000 lines and the json file contains much more.

How can I optimize this script?

```py
import json
import time
start = time.time()
print start
JsonFile=open('categories.json')
data = json.load(JsonFile)
Annotated_Data={}
FileList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("FilesNamesID.txt")]
for File in FileList:
    for key, value in data.items(): 
        if File == key:
            Annotated_Data[key]=(value)     
with open('Annotated_Files.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(Annotated_Data, outfile, indent=4)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: You should look at and examine what **Time Complexity** is and **Big O notation**.

Comment: Instead of `FileList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("FilesNamesID.txt")]` I would directly use `for File in open("FilesNamesID.txt")`. This avoids creating a 500 thousand lines big list which have to be stored in memory. So only the actual line is loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the nested for loop to look up the `File` in `data`. You could replace it with the following code:

```
for File in FileList:
    if File in data:
        Annotated_Data[File]=data[File]
```

or with a comprehension:

```
AnnotatedData = {File: data[File] for File in FileList if File in data}
```

You can also avoid copying the contents of the whole FilesNamesID.txt to the new list - you are consuming it line by line anyway - but it would be a relatively minor improvement.

Comment: It is not minor if the file has over 500 thousand lines

Comment: Minor improvement *relative* to the nested loop for each of those 500 000 lines )

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your answer is the best in term of improving the performance. However, it doesn't works if the fileID contains letters, only when the filesID contains only numbers! any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exact format of your data, but you could try speed-up your script by using `set()`:

```
json_data = '''
    {
        "file1": "data1",
        "file2": "data2",
        "file3": "data3"
    }
'''


filenames_id_txt = '''
    file1
    file3
'''

import json

data = json.loads(json_data)
lines = [l.strip() for l in filenames_id_txt.splitlines() if l.strip()]

s = set(data.keys())

Annotated_Data = {k: data[k] for k in s.intersection(lines)}

print(json.dumps(Annotated_Data))
```

Prints:

```
{"file3": "data3", "file1": "data1"}
```

**EDIT:** If I understand your question correctly, you want to find "intersection" between your JSON data and lines in your TXT file.

I chose the `set()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)) to store the JSON keys (set is collection of unique elements). The `set()` has very fast methods, one of the method is `intersection()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)), which accepts other iterators (e.g. lines from the TXT file) and return a new set with common elements.

I use this new set to construct new dictionary and output it as JSON file.

Comment: This is probably going to be difficult for a beginner to understand. But it is probably the fastest thing to do for this problem in Python. Maybe it's worth not just saying "use `set()`" but rather explain that Python has a `set` type, and that set operations such as intersection are pretty fast. That way if they know a bit of math, even if they don't know much Python, they can sort of figure out what your code is doing.

Comment: @JohnY You have right, I added some explanation at the end of my answer.